# setTimeout React: too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do something with setTimeout on a switch controller but I don't know what is the problem and I get this error when the code is run, this in fact is a custom hook I use: `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

```
import React from 'react';

const useVisibility = () => {
    const [visibility, setVisibility] = React.useState(true);
    const [firstTime, setFirstTime] = React.useState(true);
    let timeOutId;

    const removeTimer = () => {
        clearTimeout(timeOutId);
        timeOutId = 0;
    };

    React.useEffect(
        () => {
            document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', (e) => {
                if (document.hidden) {
                    switch (firstTime) {
                        case true:
                            setFirstTime(false)

                            timeOutId = setTimeout(() => {
                                setVisibility(false);
                            }, 0);
                            break;

                        default:
                            timeOutId = setTimeout(() => {
                                setVisibility('closed');
                            }, 0);
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (document.isConnected) {
                    removeTimer();
                }
            });
        },
        [visibility]
    );

    return { visibility, setVisibility };
};

export default useVisibility;
```

And here is how I'm using it, and also calling a React function inside it:

```
{
 visibility === 'closed' ? <> {cheatingPrevent()}
     <Modal onClose={() => setVisibility(true)}
       title="test"
       text="test." /> </> : null
}
```

Comment: You should return the remove function from the useEfect

Answer (score 3):

`React.useEffect` will add an event listener to `document` every time `visibility` changes as you have it in the dependency array. For each `visibilitychange` event, all the duplicate event listeners added will run.

The problem with this is you're calling `setVisibility` in `useEffect` callback which updates `visibility` which in return re-runs `useEffect`.

You don't need `visibility` in dependency array of `useEffect` hook. Pass empty array `[]`

Comment: It doesn't work, did you check the function I'm running

Comment: @recabos710 in your useCallback hook, I don't see any function getting returned